# How to setup parity light client?(warp sync is slow)

Tags: parity, light-clients, warp-sync

I have a full node synced using `--warp` but since I have a hdd, the final bit of the sync never catches up(due to the high transaction IO). How do I switch to a light clent on parity if I already have **most** of the chain data?

Answer (score 0):

1. **Delete your existing chain data**: `parity --light db kill`(this isn't a big deal as pre-verified blocks are downloaded so even from fresh, should only take a few minutes)
2. **Start the light sync:** `parity --light`